# How to change selected value of JQuery-select2 dropdown by option list Index number using JQuery

Tags: javascript, jquery, jquery-select2

Iam using dropdown box which is implemented using JQuery-select2 version 3.5.

I want to set the 2'nd item selected from the list like  `$("#fieldId").prop("selectedIndex",1)` using JQuery.

Is it possible?

Thanks in advance

Comment: What you have tried so far...

Comment: $("#fieldId").prop("selectedIndex",1);

Answer (score 3, accepted):

```
$('#fieldId').select2("val",$('#fieldId option:eq(1)').val());
/*By using eq(), the index number should be calculated from 0*/
```

or

```
$('#fieldId').select2("val",$('#fieldId option:nth-child(2)').val());
/*By using nth-child(), the index number should be calculated from 1*/
```

This may be useful

Comment: Your answer is correc but.already using this and mentioned this in comment.  Anyway accepting your answer to help others

Answer (score 0):

If you mean the `select` drop down menu then This should solve your problem

```
<select>
    <option>1st item</option>
    <option selected>2nd item</option>
    <option>3rd item</option>
</select>
```

**Edit:** You can achieve that like this

```
$('select option:nth-child(2)').attr('selected', true);
```

Comment: While loading the option list in ajax response, i have made the option selected as you said. That worked fine. Is there any other way like ' $("#fieldId").prop("selectedIndex",1); ' using JQuery?

Comment: Here I edited my answer @Pannarasu. Please don't forget to up vote and mark it as the answer

Comment: Your answer is working with normal dropdown using JQuery. But i have implemented dropdown using select2 jQuery, so it is not working. I got some idea from google and made some changes in your answer as $('#fieldId').select2("val",$('#fieldId option:eq(1)').val())  or  $('#fieldId').select2("val",$('#fieldId option:nth-child(2)').val()) . This is working well. @KANAYOAUSTINKANE. So please make changes in your answer

Answer (score 0):

```
$('#selectId').find('option').each(function(index,element){
    if(element.value.toLowerCase().trim() == 'VAL_TO_MATCH'){
         $("#selectId").prop('selectedIndex', index).change();
    }
});
```

Comment: Welcome to SO. Code-only answers may address the issue but they are more useful if you add explanation as well.